# auto refresh display table without reloading page

Tags: php, mysql

i would like to update my display data in a selected element every time i'm using ***editqtycan.php*** in a popup window. i'm creating a barcode system. Please help me how can i update it without refreshing the page time by time.

```
<?php

$sql="SELECT allinvty3.*, barcode.* , pd_stock_transfer.*, barcode.qty  as codeqty, barcode.id as barcodeid  from pd_stock_transfer 
            LEFT JOIN barcode on pd_stock_transfer.in_code = barcode.itemcode  

            INNER JOIN allinvty3 on pd_stock_transfer.in_code = allinvty3.in_code 
            where pd_stock_transfer.refnumber='$temp' and barcode.refnumber='$temp' and barcode.receivestatus='INCLUDED' group by  barcode.itemcode ORDER BY allinvty3.ecr_desc ASC ";
            $result = $conn->query($sql); 

 echo"<div style='height:450px; overflow-y: scroll;'>";
 echo "<table class='table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed '>";
            echo"<tr class='info'><th>MODEL</th><th>ITEM CODE</th><th>ACTUAL REC.</th><th>REQUEST QTY.</th><th>DIFF.</th>
            </tr>";
             echo"<font size='5'><p class='text-primary'>ACTUAL</p></font>";

            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $receivestatus =$row['receivestatus'];
            $icount = $row['codeqty'];
            $qty = $row['qty'];
            $total1 = $row['codeqty'] - $qty;

 //I want this division an auto update every time I want to edit the ***qty row***.
                echo"<tr>";
                    echo "<td align= center>".$row['ecr_desc']."</td>";
                    echo "<td align= center>".$row['itemcode']."</td>";
                    echo "<td align=center>".$row['codeqty']."</td>";
                    echo "<td align=center>".$row['qty']."</td>";
                    if ($icount >  $row['qty']){
                    echo"
                    <td bgcolor='#FF0000' align='center'>";}
                    else if ($icount <  $row['qty']){
                    echo"<td bgcolor=   '#006400' align='center'>";
                    }
                     else{
                    echo"
                    <td align='center'>";
                    }
                    {
                    echo " ".$total1."</td>";
                    }
        //this link is where I can edit the qty in a popup window. I don't want to use bodyonunload.           
         echo"<td><a href='#' onclick=PopupCenter1('editqtyscan.php?Tid=".$row['barcodeid']."','myPop2',400,400)>Edit Qty</a></td>";
                    }?>
                    </tr>
</table></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible to refresh only selected element on page. You can do it by JavaScript code with AJAX communication. You can use jQuery library to do this quickly by using it properly for your code. Read jQuery documentation for $.ajax function: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Or maybe you do not need to communicate with server PHP script. Maybe you can achieve your purpose by only using JS on client side (in a browser).

And last thing. Try to avoid mixing HTML and PHP. I mean `echo "<div></div>`"'. You can close PHP tags and write clean HTML code. It looks better and is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Well here is the answer ! You need AJAX ! Nothing new to learn ! It is just javascript code which communicate with server behind the scenes. You don't need to reload ! BEST tutorial here -> http://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp
Happy coding ☺